# Android LocationManager: unexpected behavior in Android 12

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager

Users in the field are reporting random problems with GPS location in an app.
The app has been using LocationManager for about 12 years with little modification.

I was able to see some unpredictable behavior by testing on Pixel 3 with Android 12.
The behavior includes location being off by half a mile, and not updating regularly unless some other app uses GPS.

Are there some things that are different about location manager in Android 11/12?
If so where are they documented?
The code I have has worked fine since Android 1.5.

I am using it through a library, but decompiling gave me this call:

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 250, 1, listener);
```

I changed it to

```
   mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 100, 0, listener);
```

It worked for a bit and then stopped working again.
The updates don't come in.

Does it need background location even though the documentation says I SHOULDN'T need background location to use location in an activity or foreground service?

If not, what the heck is going on?

Comment: Modern devices get location data from many, many sources including GPS, Wifi, Cell tower positioning, and others that all coordinate with one another to increase accuracy beyond just GPS (which is actually quite terrible in a lot of real world scenarios ala every city). That's precisely why the [Fused Location Provider](https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider) exists. It doesn't look like you are actually using any of those advancements since Android 1.5, is that correct?

Comment: Only gps is precise. And in the field the only thing that is usable. It should just work with only gps.

Comment: I am not using Fused Location Provider. I tried a few years ago and had an awful experience.

Comment: It would be terrible to make that required. And anti-competitive, since there are Android devices that wouldn't have it. But anyway, my users are in the field and just have GPS.

Answer (score 2):

Weve seen the same problem @nathanMDT which we logged initially with the SDK we thought was at fault, link below. The problem is Android 12 specifically and a change they made about a month ago to some google map permissions, all the relevant articles can be found in the below post. The devs dropped an update about 3 days ago in this tracker which im hoping will help. First response was "wait till Android 13". As a side note downgrading to Android 11 instantly fixes the frequency updates - not that this helps much.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/215186921?pli=1

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-unity-sdk/issues/1850

Comment: Did you find any solution or workaround? We followed [this Mapbox guide](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/core/guides/#requesting-location-updates) for location tracking using Mapbox SDK 9.7.1 and even 10.4.0. On Android 12, I see the location marker but the locationengine callback always returns the same location, even while walking outside (bearing is correct). Using the new [LocationComponentPlugin](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/api/10.3.0/mapbox-maps-android/com.mapbox.maps.plugin.locationcomponent/-location-component-plugin-impl/on-location-updated.html) brings the same results.

Comment: Yeah Ive updated the mapbox and unity tracker post below, if you get the latest Unity release and the latested android 12 fixes, the GPS problem is resolved. No need to change the plugins. The problem stems from the "best" current provider returned from android to unity, the unity team did say they've back ported it but the minimum we found it working was 2022.1.0.b11

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-input-dot-location-dot-start-doesnt-update-on-android-12

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-unity-sdk/issues/1850

Answer (score 1):

Foreground services still require background location permissions to access location.  That's because its non obvious to the user that just because there's a notification there that it's still using GPS.  And yes, this was added in Android 11:  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#bg-access-restrictions

Comment: Conflicts with what they say here: https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions The system considers your app to be using foreground location if a feature of your app accesses the device's current location in one of the following situations:

An activity that belongs to your app is visible.
Your app is running a foreground service. When a foreground service is running, the system raises user awareness by showing a persistent notification.

Comment: Based on what they said before, I expected background location permission to be denied by Google Play. They better approve it now.

Comment: And still doesn't explain why an activity in the foreground wasn't getting updates.